# Why can't I modify a list (as a whole) inside a function?

Tags: python, function, scope, global-variables

I try modifying the list `li` with function `abc`

```
li = [0, 0]
def abc(x):
    li = 8

abc(5)
li
```

which returns `[0, 0]`. On the other hand,

```
li = [0, 0]
def abc(x):
    li[0] = 8

abc(5)
li
```

returns `[8, 0]`. Could you please explain why such *micro* modification takes effect?

Comment: In your first example you create a new local variable named `li`. In the second example you don't define a new local variable, so Python searches in the surrounding scope, finds the global `li` and modifies that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clear and succinct answer @Matthias